# Numpy Array operations returning NaN values; despite no NaN values in input

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am running a Linear Regression (using Gradience Descent Analysis / GDA) using imported data from a .csv file (`data_axis` and `data` are exported dates and stock market prices respectively.) The code below returns `[nan nan nan nan nan nan]` as the theta value. The square error also returns `nan`.

Error messages: 'overflow encountered in multiply', 'invalid value encountered in add'

```
import numpy as np

Xdata = np.array(data_axis)
Xdata = Xdata.reshape(-1,2)
print(Xdata.shape)

Ydata = np.array(data[0:783])
Ydata = Ydata[::-1]
print(Ydata.shape)

def phi(x):
  return np.array([1,x[0],x[1],x[0]*x[0],x[1]*x[0],x[1]*x[1]])

def gda(X, Y):
  n= len(X)
  theta= np.zeros(len(X[0]))
  alpha= 0.5
  iterations = 1000
  for j in range(iterations):
    for i in range(len(X)):
      theta += alpha*(Y[i] - np.dot(theta,X[i]))*X[i]/n
  return theta

def linear_regression_with_features(X, Y, phi):
  phi_X = np.array([ phi(x) for x in X])
  return gda(phi_X,Y)

theta = linear_regression_with_features(Xdata, Ydata, phi)

def h(theta, x):
  return np.dot(theta,phi(x))

error = np.array([Ydata[i]-h(theta,Xdata[i]) for i in range(len(Xdata))])
s_error = np.dot(error,error)
print('theta= ', theta)
print('square error= ', s_error)

plt.plot(Xdata,Ydata,'co')
plt.plot(h(theta,Xdata),'r-')
```

The code does successfully return and plot a linear regression for randomly generated inputs `Xdata = np.random.rand(783,2)`,`Ydata = np.array([ 2-4*x[0]+3*x[1]+x[0]*x[0]+2*x[0]*x[1]-3*x[1]*x[1] for x in X])`.

I checked that there are no NaN values in the .csv file. I searched for the error message, and read that some Python & NumPy operations involving extremely small or extremely large numbers [may output a NaN value as the result](https://www.statology.org/runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-double_scalars/). Could this be my issue? Or is there something else which may be fixed?

Comment: A lot can create NaN values. A 0/0 division could also lead to NaNs (though you generally get a warning about that, or a complete error). Or infinities, and indeed very small numbers as well.

Comment: You mention there are no NaNs in the CSV file. How did you check that? You should really verify the actual input *data*, not the CSV file (that's next, if the input data turns out to be bad).

Comment: You're doing a bunch of loops, which doesn't feel very NumPy-y. I haven't looked whether they can actually be avoided, but is there a reason you're not using SciPy or Scikit-learn?

Comment: Are your random numers anywhere comparable to your actual data? For the random numbers, X is between 0 and 1, and Y roughly in the same range (just with some negative numbers). Are there any outlier data in your input dataset?

Comment: Is that so? Printing result of ```isnan``` indicated there were no NaN values in ```Xdata```, but I didn't imagine 0/0 divisions could be a problem. I'm only using NumPy out of habit

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem - it was a combination of very small values, very large values, and input matrices being the wrong shape. Here, X-axis input and Y-axis input had to be shapes (n,2) and (n,) respectively

Rounding did not help, but rearranging the data from scratch did.